# "Namespace 'global::' already contains a definition for" various items

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently updated a project I wrote in April 2013 to the latest version of Unity (OS X to Windows also, if that affects anything). I'm now getting a few errors, all of the following form:

`Assets/Scripts/PauseMenu.cs(4,14): error CS0101: The namespace`global::' already contains a definition for `PauseMenu'`

I'm not sure how to find where `PauseMenu` might be defined in the `global` namespace. Is there a way to find where it's original definition is? I didn't have this problem before moving the project over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the files. They were sitting in an "unused" directory. I'm not sure at this point why I kept those files around, but it makes sense now that this was a problem.