# (Unity) Photon join game multiple parameter errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, photon

So I am creating a multiplayer game with photon, following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93SkbMpWCGo&ab_channel=Blackthornprod

And I've reached step 5 (6-7 min) where I started to receive errors. To be specific 4 errors:

```
Assets\scripts\Multiplayer\CreateAndJoinRooms.cs(7,14): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'CreateAndJoinRooms'
Assets\scripts\Multiplayer\CreateAndJoinRooms.cs(13,17):error CS0111: Type 'CreateAndJoinRooms' already defines a member called 'CreateRoom' with the same parameter types
Assets\scripts\Multiplayer\CreateAndJoinRooms.cs(18,17):error CS0111: Type 'CreateAndJoinRooms' already defines a member called 'JoinRoom' with the same parameter types
Assets\scripts\Multiplayer\CreateAndJoinRooms.cs(23,26):error CS0111: Type 'CreateAndJoinRooms' already defines a member called 'OnJoinedRoom' with the same parameter types
```

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;

public class CreateAndJoinRooms : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public InputField createInput;
    public InputField joinInput;

    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(createInput.text);
    }

    public void JoinRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(joinInput.text);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("TestGame");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have two classes named `CreateAndJoinRooms` somewhere in your project.  The code you include in your question doesn't show that, so we have no idea exactly how that happened and can't really give a concrete answer.  See e.g. ["Namespace 'global::' already contains a definition for" various items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21970649) and [C# Unity the namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63492526).

Comment: oh, thank you. I found another copy of the script and I have now deleted it. Thanks for the help